# How to install a Linux distro from Windows without a CD or USB?

Tags: kali-linux, system-installation

I want to install Kali and have that as my only operating system but I don't have a USB, how can I do this?

Comment: Do you have RJ45 and access to another computer with the same? Is network booting possible (look in the BIOS)?

Answer (score 0):

Though I am not an expert but I think you can't. I think there is a way to directly boot from a .iso with grub but I don't think there is a way with the Windows Loader.

Answer (score 0):

To install Kali, (or any linux distro) without CD/DVD or USB pendrive, follow these steps:

1. Download `Unetbootin` from [here](http://unetbootin.github.io/).
2. Run `Unetbootin`.
3. Now, from the drop-down menu under Type: select Hard Disk.

[image]

4. Next select the Diskimage. Browse to the directory where you downloaded the iso file of Ubuntu.

[image]

5. Press OK.
6. Next when you reboot, and chose the Unetbootin choice and you will get the "Try" or "Install" option there

Comment: I tried this once, after the try/install menu it would crash/freeze. Maybe because I wrote it to a partition instead of a full drive.